# using regular expressions in telegram commands

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

Well, the following code adds a command handler for the `/start` command:

```
dp = updater.dispatcher
dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
```

I want to add a handler which would handle commands like `/download_video`, `/download_music` and so on all in one handler.

Something I thought of was this:

```
dp.add_handler(CommandHandler(r'^download', download))
```

But it doesn't work as supposed! Instead it will work when I send a non-command string of `/^download`

How should I do so?

Answer (score 3):

Late answer. A simple way is to parse all text messages and check if they start with the matching word, i.e.:

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters
import re

def parse_msg(update, context):
    if re.search("^(/test|/something_else)$", update.message.text, re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL):
       update.message.reply_text("send your content")

def main():
    updater = Updater("your_token", use_context=True)
    dp = updater.dispatcher
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, parse_msg)) # parses all text messages
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

- Test by sending a message starting by `/test` or `/something_else`
- If you plan to use this in a channel, make sure the bot has permission to read messages:

  - @Botfater > `/setprivacy` -> `@bot_name` -> `Disable`

Answer (score 0):

According to [source code](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/e0184455133677e54bf3db321256e1b3193208f8/telegram/ext/commandhandler.py#L107-L110), you can only pass strings as the `CommandHandler` parameter.

I suggest you call all commands as `/download`, it's friendly to users.

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom handler with regexp. For example, create new file with name regexp_command handler.py. Then copy in it the code writed below. Now you can use regexp as handler argument. For example, `dispatcher.add_handler(RegexpCommandHandler(r'start_[\d]+', start))`

```
import re
import warnings

from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import Handler


class RegexpCommandHandler(Handler):
    def __init__(self,
                 command_regexp,
                 callback,
                 filters=None,
                 allow_edited=False,
                 pass_args=False,
                 pass_update_queue=False,
                 pass_job_queue=False,
                 pass_user_data=False,
                 pass_chat_data=False):
        super(RegexpCommandHandler, self).__init__(
            callback,
            pass_update_queue=pass_update_queue,
            pass_job_queue=pass_job_queue,
            pass_user_data=pass_user_data,
            pass_chat_data=pass_chat_data
        )

        self.command_regexp = command_regexp

        self.filters = filters
        self.allow_edited = allow_edited
        self.pass_args = pass_args

        # We put this up here instead of with the rest of checking code
        # in check_update since we don't wanna spam a ton
        if isinstance(self.filters, list):
            warnings.warn('Using a list of filters in MessageHandler is getting '
                          'deprecated, please use bitwise operators (& and |) '
                          'instead. More info: https://git.io/vPTbc.')

    def check_update(self, update):
        if (isinstance(update, Update)
            and (update.message or update.edited_message and self.allow_edited)):
            message = update.message or update.edited_message

            if message.text and message.text.startswith('/') and len(message.text) > 1:
                command = message.text[1:].split(None, 1)[0].split('@')
                command.append(
                    message.bot.username)  # in case the command was send without a username
                print(command)

                if self.filters is None:
                    res = True
                elif isinstance(self.filters, list):
                    res = any(func(message) for func in self.filters)
                else:
                    res = self.filters(message)

                match = re.match(self.command_regexp, command[0])

                return res and (bool(match) and command[1].lower() == message.bot.username.lower())
            else:
                return False

        else:
            return False

    def handle_update(self, update, dispatcher):
        optional_args = self.collect_optional_args(dispatcher, update)

        message = update.message or update.edited_message

        if self.pass_args:
            optional_args['args'] = message.text.split()[1:]

        return self.callback(dispatcher.bot, update, **optional_args)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated version built shamelessly on @Alexandr s answer. I've simplified it and it now works on the v20.0:

`command_regex_handler.py`

```
import re

from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import Handler


class RegexpCommandHandler(Handler):
    def __init__(self, command_regexp, callback, separator="_", allow_edited=True, pass_args=True):

        super().__init__(callback)
        self.command_regexp = command_regexp
        self.separator = separator
        self.allow_edited = allow_edited
        self.pass_args = pass_args

    def check_update(self, update):
        """
        This method is called to determine if an update should be handled by this handler instance.
        """

        if (isinstance(update, Update)
                and (update.message or update.edited_message and self.allow_edited)):
            message = update.message or update.edited_message
            if message.text and message.text.startswith('/') and len(message.text) > 1:
                command = message.text[1:].split(None, 1)[0].split('@')
                command.append(
                    update.effective_user.username)  # in case the command was send without a username
                match = re.match(self.command_regexp, command[0])

                return True and (bool(match) and command[1].lower() == update.effective_user.username.lower())
            else:
                return False

        else:
            return False

    async def handle_update(self, update, application, check_result, context):
        """
        This method is called if it was determined that an update should indeed be handled by this instance.
        Splits the command by the defined separator and returns arguments.
        """
        if self.pass_args:
            message = update.message or update.edited_message
            optional_args = message.text.split(self.separator)[1:]
        else:
            optional_args = []
        return await self.callback(update, context, *optional_args)
```

And a test bot:

```
import logging
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import ApplicationBuilder, CallbackContext, CommandHandler
from command_regex_handler import RegexpCommandHandler

logging.basicConfig(
    format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
    level=logging.INFO
)


async def start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    await context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="I'm a bot, please talk to me!")


async def regexyey(update: Update, context: CallbackContext.DEFAULT_TYPE, *other_args):
    print('Passed arguments', other_args)
    await context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="worked")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    application = ApplicationBuilder().token('TOKEN').build()

    start_handler = CommandHandler('start', start)
    application.add_handler(RegexpCommandHandler(r're->[\d]+', regexyey, separator='->'))
    application.add_handler(start_handler)

    application.run_polling()
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, it's not possible using the standard tools. The current version of the framework is `20.6`.

I wrote a `RegexCommandHandler` class for my project, maybe you'll need the same functionality, so here it is:

```
import re

from typing import Optional

from telegram.ext import BaseHandler
from telegram import Update, MessageEntity
from telegram.ext import filters as filters_module


class RegexCommandHandler(BaseHandler):
    __slots__ = (
        "pattern",
        "filters"
    )

    def __init__(self, pattern: re.Pattern | str, callback, filters: Optional[filters_module.BaseFilter] = None, block: bool = True):
        super().__init__(callback, block=block)
        if isinstance(pattern, str):
            pattern = re.compile(pattern)
        self.pattern = pattern
        self.filters: filters_module.BaseFilter = (
            filters if filters is not None else filters_module.UpdateType.MESSAGES
        )

    def check_update(self, update):
        if isinstance(update, Update) and update.effective_message:
            message = update.effective_message

            if (
                    message.entities
                    and message.entities[0].type == MessageEntity.BOT_COMMAND
                    and message.entities[0].offset == 0
                    and message.text
                    and message.get_bot()
            ):
                command = message.text[1:message.entities[0].length]
                args = message.text.split()[1:]
                command_parts = command.split("@")
                command_parts.append(message.get_bot().username)

                match = self.pattern.match(command_parts[0])
                if not (match and command_parts[1].lower() == message.get_bot().username.lower()):
                    return None

                filter_result = self.filters.check_update(update)
                if filter_result:
                    return args, filter_result, match.groupdict()
                return False
        return None

    def collect_additional_context(
        self,
        context,
        update: Update,
        application,
        check_result,
    ) -> None:
        if isinstance(check_result, tuple):
            context.args = check_result[0]
            if isinstance(check_result[1], dict):
                context.update(check_result[1])
            if isinstance(check_result[2], dict):
                context.update(check_result[2])
```

It's mostly a copy-pasta of the regular ol' `CommandHandler` with the exception of it supporting regex and all the named match groups become attached to a `CallbackContext`.

Have a look at usage:

```
async def handler(update, ctx):
    preset_id = ctx.preset_id
    # do something with preset id...


app.add_handler(
    RegexCommandHandler(
        re.compile(r"use_preset_(?P<preset_id>\d+)"), 
        callback=handler
    )
)
```

Answer (score -1):

`CommandHandler` accepts tuple/list of strings as input, so you can do:

`dp.add_handler(CommandHandler(('download_video', 'download_music'), download))`

or

`dp.add_handler(CommandHandler(['download_video', 'download_music'], download))`

Comment: what if you're gonna need something like: `/game_12345`, where 12345 is a game id? This is better UX, because you can click on the command to execute it again, instead of typing it manually in case of `/game 12345`, where `/game` would be clickable, but `12345` would not.