# Telegram get message by channel ID

Tags: python, chat, telegram, channel, telethon

I am subscribed to a private telegram Channel/chat where I am not admin and the username is not public.

I can get the channel id from the url in the form https://web.telegram.org/#/im?p=c1234567890_12345678901234567890
And can read all the messages in my telegram and via my web browser.

The channel outputs data (messages) that I want to grab and format and ultimately automatically append to a csv file or such like via a bot or an app on my mac.

Is it possible to do this?

I am currently trying to do this in Python using the Telethon package.

I have been trying to access or  address the channel by ID but get errors like
No user has "c1234567890" as username
Or
No user has "-1001234567890" as username

I am trying to use the telethon client.getmessages() method but looks like it will only accept a username and not a chat or channel ID.

Any help/guidance or pointing in the right direction appreciated - I think my main issue is resolving the channel ID to a username or finding classes/methods where I can get the messages by channel ID.

Comment: your bot need [permissions to read messages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65964410/797495). Channel name may be only `1234567890`, without the "c", but this last one is just a guess.

Comment: "No user has "-1001234567890" as username" seems to imply you used a string, and not an integer. If you want to access a channel (or chat, or user) by ID, you need to use an `int`, not an `str`. `client.get_messages` does accept channel IDs as long as they're `int`.

Comment: At the moment it is just an app not a bot seeking to access the channel with my credentials (I have access)

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can used channel ID for search. use it as a int not as a String

this code will help you to understand.

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
# Remember to use your own values from my.telegram.org!
api_id = 12345
api_hash = '0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef'
client = TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash)

async def main():    
    # You can print the message history of any chat:
    # chat id is -1001209767229
    async for message in client.iter_messages(-1001209767229):
        print(message.sender.username, message.text)
        with client:
            client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```